# Macro Formatting a csv file

Tags: vba, excel

I am using a macro to generate a file with 3 columns ( A,B,C) and save it to a csv. I have everything working fine except when I save it. The file saves correct but it saves all Lines in columns after the data with a " " " in the rows of each line. I need to clean this up. The ending line will different everyday, and I need to delete from the first open line to end of workbook.

I tried this:

```
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
Range("A100:C100").Select
Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
```

But the cell reference will change everyday, so I tried:

```
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
Range("A:C").Select
Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
```

and now it deletes all data. Any help will be great Below is a example of my data and how it looks. I need to get rid of all the " " " and these only show up when I view it in notepad, but the program I use looks at the " " " as data

```
 6/27/2012 0:00,aaaa,-0.011111
 6/27/2012 0:00,bbbb,-0.22222
 6/27/2012 0:00,cccc,-0.03333
 6/27/2012 0:00,ddddd,-0.0044
 6/27/2012 0:00,xxxxxx,-0.0555
 ' '
 ' '
 ' '
 ' '
 ' '
```

Comment: Can you post a sample workbook? Or a screenshot of the data? Your description is a bit confusing.

Comment: To help clarify `The ending line will different everyday, and I need to delete from the first open line to end of workbook.` Why do you need to delete blank (open) rows, or is there data underneath a blank row that you want to eliminate? Also, can you be clearer on this `The file saves correct but it saves all Lines in columns after the data with a " " " in the rows of each line.`?

Comment: yes. Under the data I need when load this later in a notepad I have """ in all cells under the data I need.  That is why I was deleting all of it, and that cleans it up. I need to get rid of all the """ in my notepad view the program I run looks at them as data.

Comment: updated question with example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code to clean out unnecessary lines with ""

```
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Columns(1).Find("""")
Range(rng, rng.End(xlDown).End(xlToRight)).EntireRow.Delete
```

This will work so long as there is always more than 1 **"** in a line, if there is only 1, it gets a bit trickier.

Comment: I thought it was """ it is ' ', will this still work? Set rng = Columns(1).Find("""") I get this showing as a red error in my vba editor?

Comment: also the ' ' isn't visible in excel, just in notepad.

Comment: Copy the text from your file, and paste in between the outer quotes in  `Find("""")` That way you get exactly what you need.

Comment: Good. The tricky thing sometimes is to find exactly how to get at the data element that is screwing you up!